# BraodcastReceiver gets called whenever app loses focus. Any way to suppress this?

Tags: android

I have an app that downloads info from a particular website, currently set to do this once a day. The problem I have is that if I have the app open and I receive a text message, as soon as the pop up appears the download kicks in on my app. I have no idea of where to start trying to solve this. Any ideas?

Current workflow: MainActivity -> Start BroadcastReceiver, which sets alarmManager to kick off download at specified time -> another BroadcastReceiver starts an IntentService which handles the list downloading. Pretty much it.

Hopefully I've done a decent job of explaining.

Comment: _download kicks in on my app_. what's this. be specific to explain your problem.

Comment: Try verifying which action triggers your BroadcastReceiver when receiving a Text Message and when you really want to download your file. You can get the action like this: `String action = intent.getAction();`

Comment: @Adrian C. Thanks for the getAction() suggestion. Should've thought of that myself. I added it in all places I thought relevant but all returned null. I have just noticed that the same problem occurs whenever the screen rotation changes so now have at least some direction to look in.